# SwiftUI Value of type 'some View' has no member 'symbolRenderingMode'

Tags: swift, swiftui, sf-symbols

I have an SF symbol with `.symbolRenderingMode` to give it `.palette`.

```swift
Button(action: {
          self.currentview = "Form"
       })
     {
         Image(systemName: "note.text.badge.plus")
          .font(.system(size: 30))
          .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
          .foregroundStyle(Color.blue, Color.green)
                            
    }
```

but on the line

```swift
.symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
```

I get this error:

```
Value of type 'some View' has no member 'symbolRenderingMode'
```

And this one:

```
Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'palette'
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: There is no view modifier like that, did you mean `renderingMode`?

Comment: This is a new thing in iOS 15. It's not available if you are not using the Xcode beta. What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: What happens if you put it before the font modifier?

Comment: The problem was I was using `.symbolRenderingMode` instead of `.renderingMode`